# Amazon EC2 Hostname Keeps Getting Reset

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have several amazon ec2 instances running Linux AMIs based on fedora and even though I set the hostname using the command:

```
hostname example.com
```

whenever I have to reboot any of them this hostname gets reset to something ip*****, how can I make my hostname stick and make it permanent??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Calling hostname doesn't make the change permanent, it's only for the current 'boot' session. To make it permanent, you have to change `/etc/sysconfig/network`. There's a `HOSTNAME` line in there which is read by the boot scripts to set the hostname at startup.

Comment: On Ubuntu on AWS setting /etc/hostname did the trick for me.

Comment: Check out `/etc/init/hostname.conf` ;)

Comment: what about  Centos 6.3?

Comment: newbie question: Where do I find this file on a EC2 windows machine?

Comment: You have to modify /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg - see http://serverfault.com/a/563598/184114